# Errors silently thrown during debug run?

Tags: java, javaagents

I've got a pretty simple Spring application building in Maven and Eclipse. Everything is working fine, but when I debug the application, I hit a few exceptions that are never actually thrown:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/rfkrocktk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/3.0.1.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.jar
```

I'm referencing this JAR in my invocation script with:

```
-javaagent:/home/rfkrocktk/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-instrument/3.0.1.RELEASE/spring-instrument-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
```

The weird thing is, everything *works*. Without this in my startup script, load-time weaving doesn't work. With it, everything works as planned. Is there something I'm missing here? I think the `FileNotFoundException` is wrapped in a `PrivilegedActionException` as well, but since it doesn't actually throw the error, I can't get the stack trace.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Could you solve it?

Comment: I had a misconfiguration in my application, it wasn't the classpath if I remembered right.